# Why is conditional convergence an important distinction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

is it because there are theorems that hold for absolute convergence but not conditional convergence?

[What IS conditional convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566911/what-is-conditional-convergence)

Comment: One example is: absolutely convergent series can be rearranged arbitrarily, whereas for conditionally convergent series you can get different sums after rearranging terms (and in fact you can always get any sum you want, or even a divergent series).

Comment: oh okay that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of time, a tough problem involving, for example, sums and integrals, can be attacked by changing the orders of summing and integration.  When the sums converge absolutely (and the corresponding concept for the integrals) this is sound, but when dealing with conditionally convergent sums all the theorems that tell you it is safe to do this switch break down.

These nit-picking distinctions made by people in the field of "analysis" are the reason you don't have a plethora of (incorrectly) proven theorems that later turn out to be false.